# How to close all popup windows in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, popupwindow

I want to show all popup windows(already popped up and closed individually) on an image by pressing a button press and want to close all those windows on another button press. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
package com.devahead.utils
{
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;

    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
    import mx.core.Application;
    //import mx.core.FlexGlobals; // NOTE: use this import for Flex 4.x and higher
    import mx.core.IChildList;
    import mx.core.UIComponent;
    import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

    public class PopUpUtils
    {
        /**
         * Returns all the popups inside an application. Only the popups whose base
         * class is UIComponent are returned.
         *
         * @param applicationInstance
         *   Application instance. If null, Application.application is used.
         * @param onlyVisible
         *   If true, considers only the visible popups.
         * @return All the popups in the specified application.
         */
        public static function getAllPopups(applicationInstance: Object = null,
            onlyVisible: Boolean = false): ArrayCollection
        {
            var result: ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

            if (applicationInstance == null)
            {
                // NOTE: use this line for Flex 4.x and higher
                //applicationInstance = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication;

                // NOTE: use this line for Flex 3.x and lower
                applicationInstance = Application.application;
            }

            var rawChildren: IChildList = applicationInstance.systemManager.rawChildren;

            for (var i: int = 0; i < rawChildren.numChildren; i++)
            {
                var currRawChild: DisplayObject = rawChildren.getChildAt(i);

                if ((currRawChild is UIComponent) && UIComponent(currRawChild).isPopUp)
                {
                    if (!onlyVisible || UIComponent(currRawChild).visible)
                    {
                        result.addItem(currRawChild);
                    }
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        /**
         * Checks if an application has visible popups. Only the popups whose base
         * class is UIComponent are considered.
         *
         * @param applicationInstance
         *   Application instance. If null, Application.application is used.
         * @return True if there are visible popups in the specified application,
         *         false otherwise.
         */
        public static function hasVisiblePopups(applicationInstance: Object = null): Boolean
        {
            if (applicationInstance == null)
            {
                // NOTE: use this line for Flex 4.x and higher
                //applicationInstance = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication;

                // NOTE: use this line for Flex 3.x and lower
                applicationInstance = Application.application;
            }

            var rawChildren: IChildList = applicationInstance.systemManager.rawChildren;

            for (var i: int = 0; i < rawChildren.numChildren; i++)
            {
                var currRawChild: DisplayObject = rawChildren.getChildAt(i);

                if ((currRawChild is UIComponent) && UIComponent(currRawChild).isPopUp
                    && UIComponent(currRawChild).visible)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        /**
         * Closes all the popups belonging to an application. Only the popups
         * whose base class is UIComponent are considered.
         *
         * @param applicationInstance
         *   Application instance. If null, Application.application is used.
         * @return The list of the closed popups.
         */
        public static function closeAllPopups(applicationInstance: Object = null): ArrayCollection
        {
            var allPopups: ArrayCollection = getAllPopups(applicationInstance);

            for each (var currPopup: UIComponent in allPopups)
            {
                PopUpManager.removePopUp(currPopup);
            }

            return allPopups;
        }
    }
}
```

I got it from the following:
http://www.devahead.com/blog/2009/12/getting-all-the-popups-in-a-flex-application/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for (var i:int = systemManager.popUpChildren.numChildren - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    var popup:IFlexDisplayObject = IFlexDisplayObject(systemManager.popUpChildren.getChildAt(i));
    PopUpManager.removePopUp(popup);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Constantiner, I'm getting `systemManager.popUpChildren.numChildren` value as zero. So the loop is not getting executed.

Comment: Sorry, missed your point about opening windows. So you need to open all the windows first.

Comment: Hi @Constantiner,Though they are opened, the number of children is showing zero.

Comment: Hello @Constantiner, lets continue this discussion in chat.