# Close Alert box without object in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, flex3

I have an application which consists of two states(state1 and state2). Intially state1 popups and then state2 popups. On state2 there are numbers of operations which shows alert.
Now if i click logout the State2 window closes and state1 popups but alert still remains popped up,Now i dont have alert object to remove using PopUpmanger.removepopup().

Comment: Are these `Alert` calls required for operation or are they informational/debug purpose? If the latter you should ideally remove them from the release build. Also, any such popups should ideally be dealt with in the time when you're exiting `state2` and before you have reverted to `state1`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6980258/842112

Comment: Below code may help you: --///////////// for(var i:int=0;i<systemManager.popUpChildren.numChildren;i++){
var popup:IFlexDisplayObject = IFlexDisplayObject(systemManager.popUpChildren.getChildAt(i));
PopUpManager.removePopUp(popup);
}

Comment: systemManager.popUpChildren.numChildren returns 0 even alerts if alert is there

Comment: where to find alert object in systemManager.rawchildren

Comment: You could add an eventListener (`Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE`) to your state2 window and handle closing popups there

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround you can do, push all alert in to an array if alert is open and if alert is close you can pop it. If alert is open on logout you can get alert object and then you can remove by using PopUpManager.removePopUp() by for loop.

```
//Global array for your application// 
private var tempArray:Array = new Array();

//When you open first alert
var alert1:Alert = Alert.show("First Alert", "Alert");
tempArray.push(alert1);

//When you open second alert
var alert2:Alert = Alert.show("SecondAlert", "Alert");
tempArray.push(alert2);
```

//some thing like this.... not tested....

```
for(var i:int=tempArray.length-1;0< i;i--){
PopUpManager.removePopUp(tempArray[i]);
tempArray.pop();
}
```

//Below code not tested
or

```
PopUpManager.removeAllPopUps()
```

or

```
public function closeAllPopup():void
{
var systemManager:SystemManager = Application.application.systemManager
var childList:IChildList = systemManager.rawChildren
for (var i:int=childList.numChildren-1; i >=0; i– )
{
var childObject:* = childList.getChildAt(i)
if (childObject is UIComponent)
{
var uiComponent:UIComponent = childObject as UIComponent
if (uiComponent.isPopUp)
{
PopUpManager.removePopUp(uiComponent)
}
}
}
}
```

or check below link: -

```
http://www.devahead.com/blog/2009/12/getting-all-the-popups-in-a-flex-application/
```

Comment: in Application approx there are 1000 of alerts so cant even think of doin so