# Flex - Close all popups from a popup

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex-spark

I've been searching around for this issue for a while, but no-one seems to have had the same issue.

I have a popup that asks the user whether or not to try to reconnect to the server. If they choose no, I want to close all popups and redirect to the login view. The problem with solutions such as

[How to close all popup windows in Flex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980160/how-to-close-all-popup-windows-in-flex)

is that if you remove the popup that is currently dispatching the call, it will try to remove the same popup twice, causing a nullpointer in AlertAccImpl.as, which is ofcourse not what I want.

Do you have any suggestions of how to find the "current" popup reference so that I can avoid closing it twice?

EDIT: Popups are opened by Alert.show(...), so they are managed by PopUpManager.

Comment: How have you created the popups?  Is this an AIR app using separate windows? Or popup windows within the application created with the PopupManager?

Comment: Why don't you just keep track of popups that you open/close in an array. Then when you want to close all of them, you can just iterate over your array. Also, it's really hard to give you an answer w/out seeing what you're doing (ie: show some code).

Comment: If your popups are all of a same type then, I'd extend all the popups with customWindow, on creation, i'd listen for a global event(Like FlexTopLevelApplication or systemmanager alias system).
When the user hits 'No' i'd dispatch this event to  the system where the popup are being displayed and listening, they would close them selves catching this event.

Comment: @Reboog711, We are using Alert.show, so the PupUpManager is implicitly used.

Comment: @SunilD. I am working in a large coorperation and want to make sure that all future popups also are closed. The extending/compounding solution relies heavily on other developers NOT using Alert.Show, which may be a future risk. I want to avoid this if possible.